# swift3 - update ui with data from background

Tags: swift3

having hard time with UI updating with data from background thread. I read tons of docs but still missing something...

```
func getData(){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let token = GetTokenOperation()

        token.success = { item in
            print("Success")
        }

        token.failure = {error in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        NetworkQueue.shared.addOperation(op: token)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // qos' default value is ´DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default`
            self.updateUI()
        }
    }

}
```

self.updateUI() is executed before "Success" is printed. When I put self.updateUI() inside of the closure token.success it crashes indeed.

Comment: As i know, Apple doesn't allow to update UI from background thread.

Comment: Yeah, that's the reason why I'm asking how to do it properly.

Comment: Ok so at least it's a challenge in Swift3.

Comment: Do you want to update the UI after         NetworkQueue.shared.addOperation(op: token)
finishes? If yes, then this is the problem: there's no guarantee that self.updateUI will be launched after that operations has finished.

Comment: So that NetworkQueue.shared.addOperation(op: token) is creating another thread, which is not catched by my DispatchQueue? How can I workaround it?

Comment: Apple is allowed updeting UI in bacground thread. Look my answer in below.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried this?

```
    token.success = { item in
        print("Success")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.updateUI()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Will also probably want to updateUI in case of failure. but OOPer is right-- the original code added updateUI to the queue right after adding the token to the network queue. Who knows which would execute first? Instead you could add an "in progress" UI state and updateUI in all three places...

Comment: yes, I tried to put DispatchQueue into the success closure but I need to let finish token.success func first to do the job with token (parsing, storing etc.)

Answer (score 1):

in my case, i needed to update UI in background mode. I was a UIProgressView and timer. While time consuming, i updated progress view to show remaing time. But the user when clicked home button, app goes to bacground mode and UI will not update. To overcome this problem, i use DispatchQueue with .background option.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let fractionalProgress = Float(self.counter) / 60.0
                let animated = self.counter != 0
                self.barProgress.setProgress(fractionalProgress, animated: animated)
            }
        }
```

I hope, this will help someone.